# json.Marshal map to JSON array

Tags: json, go

When i try Marshal a map, json.Marshal return:

```
{"Map Key":"Map Value"}...
```

This is normal behavior. But i can marshal this to:

```
{"Map":[{"Name":"Map Key","Date":"Map Value"},{"Name":"Map Key2","Date":"Map Value2"}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a custom [`json.Marshaler`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) interface to do that, for example:

```
type mapInfo struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Date string `json:"date"`
}

type CustomMap map[string]string

func (cm CustomMap) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    // if you want to optimize you can use a bytes.Buffer and write the strings out yourself.
    var out struct {
        Map []mapInfo `json:"map"`
    }
    for k, v := range cm {
        out.Map = append(out.Map, mapInfo{k, v})
    }
    return json.Marshal(out)
}

func (cm CustomMap) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    var out struct {
        Map []mapInfo `json:"map"`
    }
    if err = json.Unmarshal(b, &out); err != nil {
        return
    }
    for _, v := range out.Map {
        cm[v.Name] = v.Date
    }
    return
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/7AHbAhJo-o)